# Subset using i statement dynamically created from another data.table's variables

Tags: r, data.table

I have data similar to the following:

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(ID=1:10, Status=c(rep("OUT",2),rep("IN",2),"ON",rep("OUT",2),rep("IN",2),"ON"), 
                 t1=round(rnorm(10),1), t2=round(rnorm(10),1), t3=round(rnorm(10),1), 
                 t4=round(rnorm(10),1), t5=round(rnorm(10),1), t6=round(rnorm(10),1),
                 t7=round(rnorm(10),1),t8=round(rnorm(10),1))

    ID Status   t1   t2   t3   t4   t5   t6   t7   t8
 1:  1    OUT -0.6  1.5  0.9  1.4 -0.2  0.4  2.4  0.5
 2:  2    OUT  0.2  0.4  0.8 -0.1 -0.3 -0.6  0.0 -0.7
 3:  3     IN -0.8 -0.6  0.1  0.4  0.7  0.3  0.7  0.6
 4:  4     IN  1.6 -2.2 -2.0 -0.1  0.6 -1.1  0.0 -0.9
 5:  5     ON  0.3  1.1  0.6 -1.4 -0.7  1.4 -0.7 -1.3
 6:  6    OUT -0.8  0.0 -0.1 -0.4 -0.7  2.0  0.2  0.3
 7:  7    OUT  0.5  0.0 -0.2 -0.4  0.4 -0.4 -1.8 -0.4
 8:  8     IN  0.7  0.9 -1.5 -0.1  0.8 -1.0  1.5  0.0
 9:  9     IN  0.6  0.8 -0.5  1.1 -0.1  0.6  0.2  0.1
10: 10     ON -0.3  0.6  0.4  0.8  0.9 -0.1  2.2 -0.6
```

I need to apply constraints to `dt` similar to the following (which are read in from a csv using fread):

```
dt_constraints <- data.table(columns=c("t1","t3","t7","t8"), operator=c(rep(">=",2),rep("<=",2)), 
                         values=c(-.6,-.5,2.4,.5))

    columns operator    values
1   t1       >=         -0.6
2   t3       >=         -0.5
3   t7       <=          2.4
4   t8       <=          0.5
```

I can easily subset `dt` by typing in the various constraints in the `i` statement:

```
dt_sub <- dt[t1>=-.6 & t3 >=-.5 & t7<=2.4 & t8<=.5,] 

    ID  Status  t1  t2  t3   t4  t5   t6    t7   t8
1   1   OUT   -0.6  1.5 0.9  1.4 -0.2  0.4  2.4  0.5
2   2   OUT    0.2  0.4 0.8 -0.1 -0.3 -0.6  0   -0.7
3   5   ON     0.3  1.1 0.6 -1.4 -0.7  1.4 -0.7 -1.3
4   7   OUT    0.5  0  -0.2 -0.4  0.4 -0.4 -1.8 -0.4
5   9   IN     0.6  0.8-0.5  1.1 -0.1  0.6  0.2  0.1
6   10  ON    -0.3  0.6 0.4  0.8  0.9 -0.1  2.2 -0.6
```

But, since the constraints are constantly changing (a new constrants csv is read in each time), I am looking for an efficient way to programatically apply the constraints directly from `dt_constraints` to subset `dt`.  The actual data is quite large as is the number of constraints so efficiency is key.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `paste` it as a single string and then do the `eval`

```
dt[eval(parse(text=do.call(paste, c(dt_constraints, collapse= ' & '))))]
#   ID Status   t1  t2   t3   t4   t5   t6   t7   t8
#1:  1    OUT -0.6 1.5  0.9  1.4 -0.2  0.4  2.4  0.5
#2:  2    OUT  0.2 0.4  0.8 -0.1 -0.3 -0.6  0.0 -0.7
#3:  5     ON  0.3 1.1  0.6 -1.4 -0.7  1.4 -0.7 -1.3
#4:  7    OUT  0.5 0.0 -0.2 -0.4  0.4 -0.4 -1.8 -0.4
#5:  9     IN  0.6 0.8 -0.5  1.1 -0.1  0.6  0.2  0.1
#6: 10     ON -0.3 0.6  0.4  0.8  0.9 -0.1  2.2 -0.6
```

---

If we are using `tidyverse`, then

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
   filter(!!rlang::parse_expr(do.call(paste, c(dt_constraints, collapse= ' & '))))
#  ID Status   t1  t2   t3   t4   t5   t6   t7   t8
#1  1    OUT -0.6 1.5  0.9  1.4 -0.2  0.4  2.4  0.5
#2  2    OUT  0.2 0.4  0.8 -0.1 -0.3 -0.6  0.0 -0.7
#3  5     ON  0.3 1.1  0.6 -1.4 -0.7  1.4 -0.7 -1.3
#4  7    OUT  0.5 0.0 -0.2 -0.4  0.4 -0.4 -1.8 -0.4
#5  9     IN  0.6 0.8 -0.5  1.1 -0.1  0.6  0.2  0.1
#6 10     ON -0.3 0.6  0.4  0.8  0.9 -0.1  2.2 -0.6
```

Comment: the data.table solution works perfectly.  I know it is best to use column names, but how would you perform the same task if the column numbers were listed in the constraints table instead of column names, ie `dt_constraints <- data.table(columns=c(3,5,9,10), operator=c(rep(">=",2),rep("<=",2)), 
                             values=c(-.6,-.5,2.4,.5))`  .  Thanks

Comment: @FG7 In that case `dt_constraints[, columns := names(dt)[columns]]` then do the `paste` as in the above

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I need an additional bit of info: the number of observations that passed each constraint and that failed each constraint. Ideally, I could get an output table similar to the `dt_constraints` table but with two additional columns, one for number of observations that passed and one for number of observations that failed.  Any ideas?

Comment: @FG7 Sorry, I am not getting your comment.  Could you please post as a new question?

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  As requested, I posted the new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596739/count-observations-that-pass-and-fail-each-condition).  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: if I created a character vector of the constraints using `constraints <- paste0(dt_constraints$columns,dt_constraints$operator,dt_constraints$values)` and I wanted to apply just the first constraint, how would I do that?  I thought `dt[get(constraints[1])]` would work but it didn't. Also, `dt[(constraints[1])]` didn't work.

Comment: @FG7  When you paste the columns, it is going as a single entity.  If you don't want to use a particular column, then remove it from the paste step

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative approach which uses *non-equi joins* for subsetting:

```
thresholds <- dt_constraints[, values]
cond <- dt_constraints[, paste0(columns, operator, "V", .I)]
dt[dt[as.list(thresholds), on = cond, which = TRUE]]
```

> ```
>    ID Status   t1  t2   t3   t4   t5   t6   t7   t8
> 1:  1    OUT -0.6 1.5  0.9  1.4 -0.2  0.4  2.4  0.5
> 2:  2    OUT  0.2 0.4  0.8 -0.1 -0.3 -0.6  0.0 -0.7
> 3:  5     ON  0.3 1.1  0.6 -1.4 -0.7  1.4 -0.7 -1.3
> 4:  7    OUT  0.5 0.0 -0.2 -0.4  0.4 -0.4 -1.8 -0.4
> 5:  9     IN  0.6 0.8 -0.5  1.1 -0.1  0.6  0.2  0.1
> 6: 10     ON -0.3 0.6  0.4  0.8  0.9 -0.1  2.2 -0.6
> ```