# Count observations that pass and fail each condition

Tags: r, data.table

This is a follow-up to a previous question shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537760/subset-using-i-statement-dynamically-created-from-another-data-tables-variables).

I have data similar to the following:

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(ID=1:10, Status=c(rep("OUT",2),rep("IN",2),"ON",rep("OUT",2),rep("IN",2),"ON"), 
                 t1=round(rnorm(10),1), t2=round(rnorm(10),1), t3=round(rnorm(10),1), 
                 t4=round(rnorm(10),1), t5=round(rnorm(10),1), t6=round(rnorm(10),1),
                 t7=round(rnorm(10),1),t8=round(rnorm(10),1))

    ID Status   t1   t2   t3   t4   t5   t6   t7   t8
 1:  1    OUT -0.6  1.5  0.9  1.4 -0.2  0.4  2.4  0.5
 2:  2    OUT  0.2  0.4  0.8 -0.1 -0.3 -0.6  0.0 -0.7
 3:  3     IN -0.8 -0.6  0.1  0.4  0.7  0.3  0.7  0.6
 4:  4     IN  1.6 -2.2 -2.0 -0.1  0.6 -1.1  0.0 -0.9
 5:  5     ON  0.3  1.1  0.6 -1.4 -0.7  1.4 -0.7 -1.3
 6:  6    OUT -0.8  0.0 -0.1 -0.4 -0.7  2.0  0.2  0.3
 7:  7    OUT  0.5  0.0 -0.2 -0.4  0.4 -0.4 -1.8 -0.4
 8:  8     IN  0.7  0.9 -1.5 -0.1  0.8 -1.0  1.5  0.0
 9:  9     IN  0.6  0.8 -0.5  1.1 -0.1  0.6  0.2  0.1
10: 10     ON -0.3  0.6  0.4  0.8  0.9 -0.1  2.2 -0.6
```

I apply constraints to `dt` that are read in from a csv:

```
dt_constraints <- data.table(columns=c("t1","t3","t7","t8"), operator=c(rep(">=",2),rep("<=",2)), 
                             values=c(-.6,-.5,2.4,.5))

    columns operator    values
1   t1       >=         -0.6
2   t3       >=         -0.5
3   t7       <=          2.4
4   t8       <=          0.5
```

@akrun provided a very efficient solution:

```
dt[eval(parse(text=do.call(paste, c(dt_constraints, collapse= ' & '))))]
```

I need two additional bits of information: the number of observations that pass each constraint and the number of observations that fail each constraint.  The output could look like this:

```
    columns operator    values  obs_pass  obs_fail
1   t1       >=         -0.6       8         2
2   t3       >=         -0.5       8         2
3   t7       <=          2.4       10        0
4   t8       <=          0.5       9         1
```

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could construct the `on=` expression and do a join for each row:

```
dt_constraints[, onexpr := sprintf("%s%sv", columns, operator)]

dt_constraints[, n_pass := dt[.(v = values), on=onexpr, .N, by=.EACHI]$N, by=onexpr]
dt_constraints[, n_fail := nrow(dt) - n_pass ]
```

The `by=.EACHI` should allow you to use the same `onexpr` with multiple different `values`, though I guess there are better ways to do that. If `onexpr` are unique, there's instead...

```
dt_constraints[, n_pass := dt[.(v = values), on=onexpr, .N], by=onexpr]
dt_constraints[, n_fail := nrow(dt) - n_pass ]
```

---

To filter on all constraints at once using this approach:*

```
n_grp = nrow(dt_constraints)
w = seq_len(nrow(dt))
dt[dt_constraints[, {
  w <- w[dt[w][.(v = values), on=onexpr, which=TRUE]]
  if (.GRP == n_grp) w
}, by=onexpr]$V1]

   ID Status   t1  t2   t3   t4   t5   t6   t7   t8
1:  1    OUT -0.6 1.5  0.9  1.4 -0.2  0.4  2.4  0.5
2:  2    OUT  0.2 0.4  0.8 -0.1 -0.3 -0.6  0.0 -0.7
3:  5     ON  0.3 1.1  0.6 -1.4 -0.7  1.4 -0.7 -1.3
4:  7    OUT  0.5 0.0 -0.2 -0.4  0.4 -0.4 -1.8 -0.4
5:  9     IN  0.6 0.8 -0.5  1.1 -0.1  0.6  0.2  0.1
6: 10     ON -0.3 0.6  0.4  0.8  0.9 -0.1  2.2 -0.6
```

This works iteratively like a loop, only checking those rows (`w`) for which prior constraints held.

*assuming no repeated `onexpr`, since that wouldn't make sense.. you could first filter per `onexpr` to max `values` for `>=` and min for `<=`.

---

A followup question from the OP:

> How would I alter the code to perform the following: (1)give pass/fail counts for the first constraint; (2)using data subsetted by passes from the first constraint, give the pass/fail counts for the second constraint; (3)using data subsetted by passes from the second constraint, give the pass/fail counts for the third constraint, etc.

```
# iteratively count pass/fail
w = seq_len(nrow(dt))
dt_constraints[, {
  w0 <- w
  w <- w[dt[w][.(v = values), on=onexpr, which=TRUE]]
  .(n_pass = length(w), n_fail = length(w0) - length(w))
}, by=onexpr]
```

Comment: the pass/fail code works perfectly.  Thanks so much.  How would I alter the code to perform the following: (1)give pass/fail counts for the first constraint; (2)using data subsetted by passes from the first constraint, give the pass/fail counts for the second constraint; (3)using data subsetted by passes from the second constraint, give the pass/fail counts for the third constraint, etc.  The output would look just like the output shown in the question but with different pass/fail counts according to the new methodology.

Comment: @FG7 Some changes to the loop seem to work. I now see 8 6 6 6 passes; posted it in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public Let me know there or here if it's unclear.

Comment: Frank provided this code that performs exactly what I asked in my comment: `dt_constraints[, onexpr := sprintf("%s%sv", columns, operator)]`;# iteratively count pass/fail
`n_grp = nrow(dt_constraints);
w = seq_len(nrow(dt));
dt_constraints[, {
  w0 <- w
  w <- w[dt[w][.(v = values), on=onexpr, which=TRUE]]
  .(n_pass = length(w), n_fail = length(w0) - length(w))
}, by=onexpr]`

Comment: @FG7 Ok, I've now added it to the answer. Feel free to edit it further.